# How can I make sure I only output a 6-digit, 0-padded hexadecimal value in C++?

Tags: c++, string, hex, stringstream

Basically, I am trying to generate the hexadecimal value given the values of Red, Green, and Blue... I am able to convert everything to hex but I would like the outcome to be a 6-digit hexadecimal number that is padded with 0's if there are only 4 outputted digits.

Here's what I have:"

```
int main() {
stringstream hexstring;
int red,green,blue;
cout << "Red: ";cin >> red;
cout << "Green: ";cin >> green;
cout << "Blue: ";cin >> blue;

hexstring << hex << setfill('0')  << setw(6) << uppercase << red << green  << blue;

cout << "#" << hexstring.str();



}
```

Here is the output when I use 0 for Red, 1 for Green, and 43 for blue:

```
Red: 0
Green: 1
Blue: 43
#00000012B
```

This adds 6 zeros because my setw is 6. I can set it to 2 zeros to get the total of 6 digits but if I change the values of red, green, blue I would have to also change the value of setw...

How can I make it consistently output a 6 digit number for all values within 255?

Comment: The setting by `setw()` only applies to the next value output..   Try outputting `setw(2) << red << setw(2) << green << setw(2) << blue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setw` affects [only the next output field](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw).

What you probably wanted to write was:

```
hexstring << hex << setfill('0') << uppercase
          << setw(2) << red
          << setw(2) << green
          << setw(2) << blue;
```

Comment: This seemed to have solved my problem! I was not aware that setw was only applicable to the next output. Thank you!